# VBS code to resolve IP address from hostname?

Tags: vbscript

Can anyone make this code from visual basic into VBS code?

It's tell me the IP address of the site in this example I use Google

```
Dim hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com")
    Dim ip As IPAddress() = hostname.AddressList
    Debug.Print(ip(0).ToString())
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a VB.NET or C# DLL (which you already did by your example) and make it visible for COM. Then you can use it in VBS.

Can can find several tutorials in the web:

- [How to call a .NET DLL from a VBScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79314/How-to-call-a-NET-DLL-from-a-VBScript)
- [Create a DLL by CSharp or VB.Net for VBA](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html)
- [Exposing .NET Components to COM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM)
- [Best Practice in Writing a COM-Visible Assembly (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/612604/Best-Practice-in-Writing-a-COM-Visible-Assembly-Cs)

Comment: can you recommend vbs editor or can we use visual studio ?

Comment: activex component can't create object  this error come out when running script